# What is the best way to shedule a function with Java and H2 database?

Tags: java, h2

**Context**

My objective is to change the status of `myObject` if the day's date is equal to the date stored in `myObject` entity.

So, can you tell me and explain me what is the best way to execute a function every day at a specific time with H2 database and Java?

**My entity**

```
@Entity
public MyObject {

    @Id
    private String id;
    private LocalDate endDate;
    private boolean status; // true: on going , false: ended

    ...

}
```

**My idea**

Used the annotation @Schedule like this

```
@Scheduled(cron = "0 0 0 * * ?")
public void checkMyObjectsEnd() {
     ...
}
```

**Conclusion**

Or maybe H2 has native functions to do this? Like `CREATE EVENT` on SQL.

Thanks for your advice.

Comment: what's wrong with corn job using `@Schedule`

Comment: Nothing but I don't know if it's the best way to do that.

Comment: @Deadpool Or maybe rutabaga job?

Comment: if you have to update myobject values through java code then i will suggest with `@Schedule`, but if you like to just update date or some thing the look fir database event

Comment: I want to update `status` if `endDate == current_date`. So execute it only one time per day.